# In Android 10 getDeviceID value is null

Tags: google-contacts-api

In android 10, couldn't get device id using permission "READ_PHONE_STATE". I got an error while trying to get deviceID "**The user 10296 does not meet the requirements to access device identifiers**". I referred the developer site, but couldn't get proper solution. Also "**READ_PRIVILEGE_PHONE_STATE**" permission also not accessible.

Please prefer any solution to get deviceID from Android 10 mobile's and help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

`getDeviceId()` has been **deprecated** since API level 26.

`"READ_PRIVILEGE_PHONE_STATE"` is only accessible by The best practices suggest that you should "Avoid using hardware identifiers." for unique identifiers.  You can use an instance id from firebase e.g `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getId();`.

Or you can generate a custom globally-unique ID (GUID) to uniquely identify the app instance e.g 
`String uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();`

or the least recommended way

```
String deviceId = android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(
                context.getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Comment: Values changing for different apps!

Comment: But according to Firebase documentation 

Instance ID is stable except when:
1) App deletes Instance ID
2) App is restored on a new device
3) User uninstalls/reinstall the app
4) User clears app data

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this one, it's getting token from Firebase:-

> String deviceId = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

and this way is also working:-

> String deviceId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

Comment: have you checked it on different apps on same device, providing same value?

Comment: But according to Firebase documentation Instance ID is stable except when: 1) App deletes Instance ID 2) App is restored on a new device 3) User uninstalls/reinstall the app 4) User clears app data

Answer (score 1):

As per the latest release in Android 10, Restriction on non-resettable device identifiers.
pps must have the **READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE** privileged permission in order to access the device's non-resettable identifiers, which include both **IMEI** and **serial number**.

[image]

[Check this](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes) for Privacy Changes in Android 10

To avoid such scenarios use `UUID.randomUUID().toString()` that represents an immutable universally unique identifier (UUID). A UUID represents a 128-bit value.

Answer (score 0):

This is the definitive solution !

```
String myuniqueID;   
int myversion = Integer.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK);
    if (myversion < 23) {
        WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo info = manager.getConnectionInfo();
        myuniqueID= info.getMacAddress();
        if (myuniqueID== null) {
            TelephonyManager mngr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            myuniqueID= mngr.getDeviceId();
        }
    }
    else if (myversion > 23 && myversion < 29) {
        TelephonyManager mngr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        myuniqueID= mngr.getDeviceId();
    }
    else
    {
        String androidId = Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        myuniqueID= androidId;
    }
```

Comment: no, its not. It misses API level 29 and above