# How to get Device unique Id in my android application?

Tags: android, telephonymanager

`android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getDeviceId()` is not working after migrating to `API level 29` (Android 10), as it's throwing `SecurityException`. 
Please anyone can help out me to get a unique device id.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Android 10 getDeviceID value is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58022573/in-android-10-getdeviceid-value-is-null)

Answer (score 3):

As per the latest release in Android 10, Restriction on non-resettable device identifiers.
PPS must have the **READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE** privileged permission in order to access the device's non-resettable identifiers, which include both **IMEI** and **serial number**.

`"READ_PRIVILEGE_PHONE_STATE"` is only accessible by The best practices suggest that you should "Avoid using hardware identifiers." for unique identifiers.  You can use an instance id from firebase e.g `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getId();`.

Or you can go with this also,

```
String deviceId = android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(
                    context.getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use the below code:**

```
 public String androidId;

 androidId = String
                .format("%16s", Settings.Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID))
                .replace(' ', '0');
```

Answer (score 1):

> You can use below which is preferrable which has the least chances of
>   reset.

```
private String android_id = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),
                                                        Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Please refer [THIS](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids) from which you can decide the preferable one.

Answer (score 0):

set this permission in manifeast:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Now use this to get unique no:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
  telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your project contains firebase. 
use this --> FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()

Answer (score -1):

getDeviceId is deprecated you can use this method to get the device IMEI

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        IMEINumber = telephonyMgr.getImei();
    } else {
        IMEINumber = telephonyMgr.getDeviceId();
    }
```